# Union of Associated Primes being finite.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with unit. Let $I=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_t)$ be a nonzero ideal of $R$. Define $I_n=(x_1^n, x_2^n,...,x_t^n)$.

1. Are there known results about $\cup_n \operatorname{Ass}(R/I_n)$ being finite?
2. More generally, let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Are there any results about $\cup_n\operatorname{Ass}(M/I_nM)$ being finite?

Added Later: Is something known about $\cup_n\operatorname{Ass}(I^n/I_n)$?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-074-01/S0002-9939-1979-0521865-8/S0002-9939-1979-0521865-8.pdf) could help you.

Comment: @YACP Thanks, i know this result but so far it has not helped me, so i was wondering if someone else has proved the result i ask above.

Answer (score 1):

The set in question can be infinite when the ring has prime characteristic. See Theorem 5.1 of [Associated primes of local cohomology modules and Frobenius powers](http://people.reed.edu/~iswanson/lcc.pdf), a paper by Singh and Swanson that appeared in Int. Math. Research Notices in 2004.  In that paper, they only consider $I_n$ for $n$ of the form $n=p^e$, where $p=\operatorname{char}(R)$, and already the union becomes infinite.